# Draw on/directly above desktop?

Tags: objective-c, macos

Is there a way to force a window directly above the desktop and make it transparent? Basically I want a way to draw an image and animation on the desktop so that it integrates (ie. a clock that sits on your desktop, below other windows, has a transparent background, etc).

Also, if you have a solution, is it an official API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an NSWindow initialised with style NSBorderlessWindowMask and make it floating

`setLevel:NSFloatingWindowLevel`

You can place your view hierarchy into that window.